# On using Python to solve Time Independent Schrodinger Equation, the eigenfunctions have their values "pushed" to one of the boundaries?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, software

I am having trouble using numerical methods to solve Time Independent Schrodinger Equation. I am considering a quartic potential function: $$ V(x) = x^4 -4x^2.$$
$$
-\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2} + V(x) \psi(x) = E \psi(x)
$$

I wish to get a few solutions of the eigenproblem (about 150).

Here is the code I have written:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def solveTISE(xmin,xmax,h,potFunc,params):
    xvec = np.arange(xmin,xmax,h) 
    Nx = len(xvec)
    potFunctVec = potFunc(xvec,params)
    mat = -((np.tri(Nx,Nx,1)-np.tri(Nx,Nx,-2)-3.*np.eye(Nx))/h**2-np.diag(potFunctVec))
    print(mat)
    eigenValues,eigenVectors = np.linalg.eig(mat)
    idx = eigenValues.argsort()[::1]   
    eigenValues = eigenValues[idx]
    eigenVectors = eigenVectors[:,idx]
    return eigenValues,eigenVectors,xvec
   
def doubleWell(x,params):
    return np.piecewise(x, [x < 0, x >= 0], [lambda x : params[2]*(x**4 - params[0]*x**2), lambda x :  params[3]*(x**4 - params[1]*x**2)] )

betaValue = 0.01;
hValue = 0.01;
eigEnergy1i, eigFunc1i, xvec1i = solveTISE(-10,10,hValue,doubleWell,[4,4,1,1]);

plt.plot(xvec1i,eigFunc1i[0]);
plt.show()
plt.plot(xvec1i,eigFunc1i[1]);
plt.show()
```

However, I get the following output:

[image]
[image]

When I changed the limits of x to : -20 and 20, the resulting wavefunction (the 0th index one/lowest energy state) looked like this:

[image]

I don't know why the wavefunction is being "pushed" to the right boundary.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a little more info? Define "TISE" so we know what problem you're attacking.  How did you get data for [-60, +60] if your input was [-20,+20] ?   By the way, since your potential function is quadratic in  $x^2$ you may be able to simplify your work.

Comment: I'd recommend testing code first with problems where you know the solution analytically to test it. For example a simple harmonic potential. Does your script work there ?

Comment: Hi @CarlWitthoft! Thanks for the remarks. I have edited the questions to add the correct image and stated that TISE is the time-independent Schrodinger equation.

Comment: Hi @HansWurst! I did test the code for Infinite Potential Well and worked fine for it. However, the code had the same issues for harmonic potential.

Comment: Please note that generally, if you want help with your code, the code should be complete: i.e. runnable without second-guessing what is missing. This time I've completed your code in my edit.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script looks fine on first glance. Your problem is that your eigenfunctions are the columns of your eigFunc1 Matrix and not the rows. Use this to plot them.

```
plt.plot(xvec1i,eigFunc1i[:,n]);
```

where n is the integer of the corresponding eigenfunction. I.e. to plot the groundstate use

```
plt.plot(xvec1i,eigFunc1i[:,0]);
```

Also note that `some_array[::1]` doesn't change the array, as you you are stepping over all values with a step size of 1.

EDIT:

Due to popular demand a small plot of the first eigenvectors n=0 and n=1 at the height of their eigenvalue as baseline which can be read off at the left hand y-axis.

[image]

The figure was created with

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xvec1i,eigFunc1i[:,0]+eigEnergy1i[0], c="b", lw=3);
ax.plot(xvec1i,eigFunc1i[:,1]+eigEnergy1i[1], c="orange", lw=3);
ax.axhline(eigEnergy1i[0],c="b", alpha=0.5, lw=3, label="n=0")
ax.axhline(eigEnergy1i[1], c="orange", alpha=.5, lw=3, label="n=1")
ax_twinx = ax.twinx()
ax_twinx.plot(xvec1i,doubleWell(xvec1i,[4,4,1,1]))
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlim(-10, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! It is working now.

Comment: @PhysicsKidDyinginSchool Well then, update your question to include the correct plots! I'm curious to see what they look like! :)

Comment: @Philip Ideally Hanswurst should post the correct plots, rather than including the "answer" material in the question.  Given the completenesss of the code & parameters, we all should be able to plot on our own :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Good point! I thought it was a little forward to ask HansWurst to do it, which is why I asked the OP :) But you are right, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Your another (small) problem is that your values of $x$, called `xvec`, are not in the range $\{-10, -9.99, \dots, +9.99, +10\}$. Instead they lack the $+10$, because `arange(begin,end,step)` returns the range `[begin,end)`. The result for your code is that the states that should have very close energies will instead differ more than expected, due to the broken symmetry. The fix for this is to replace your generation of `xvec` with

```
    xvec = np.arange(xmin,xmax+h,h)
```

This is much better, but it still gives you not ideal values, so the precision of the eigenvalues will be a bit smaller than you may like. Here's the output of `print(xvec)` after setting `np.set_printoptions(precision=17)`:

```
[-10.                 -9.99               -9.98              ...
   9.979999999999574   9.989999999999574   9.999999999999574]
```

I suppose it's due to the way `arange()` is implemented. To fix this, you can try to make sure that the step is integral, so that you don't accumulate too much rounding error. An example (just a dirty hack for demonstration, not intended for production):

```
    xvec = np.arange(xmin*1000,(xmax+h)*1000,h*1000)/1000
```

This code does generate

```
[-10.    -9.99  -9.98 ...   9.98   9.99  10.  ]
```

Comment: You sure you're not just running into floating point precision there?  There's no way Python stores the apparent value "9.98" as a float without the binary precision error   In R, for example,  ` x <- rep(-10,10);  for (j in 2:10) x[j] = x[j-1]+0.01
    sprintf("%1.20f", x)  
#   [1] "-10.00000000000000000000" "-9.99000000000000021316" 
 [3] "-9.98000000000000042633"  "-9.97000000000000063949" 
 [5] "-9.96000000000000085265"  "-9.95000000000000106581" 
 [7] "-9.94000000000000127898"  "-9.93000000000000149214" 
 [9] "-9.92000000000000170530"  "-9.91000000000000191847" `

Comment: @CarlWitthoft indeed, almost all of these values are not representable in `binary64`. But this is no excuse for using a numerically poor algorithm of generating a range. If you just accumulate `0.01` like `x[n]=x[n-1]+step`, you'll get worse precision than if you calculate it as `x[n]=xFirst+(xLast-xFirst)*n/(N-1)`. This is because roundoff error happens on each iteration when you accumulate. Unfortunately, it seems that `numpy.arange` does it the former, poor, way.